# How to implement docusign rest api in php for creating envelop with eventnotification in json?

Tags: docusignapi, webhooks

How to implement docusign Embedded Signing (REST API PHP) for creating envelop with template roles,tabs and event notification (webhook for getting signed status) in json body/format?How can I get the signed status?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code taken from a blog [post on this topic](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-add-a-connect-webhook-to-your-envelopes)
You will need the [DocuSign.eSign PHP Package](https://packagist.org/packages/docusign/esign-client) for this ([PHP SDK](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools/php/)).

```
$envelopeDefinition = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
$eventNotification = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EventNotification();
# Set up the endpoint URL to call (it must be using HTTPS and at least TLS1.1 or higher)
$eventNotification->setUrl('https:\\myapp.somedomain.com');
# DocuSign will retry on failure if this is set
$eventNotification->setRequireAcknowledgment('true');
# This would send the documents together with the event to the endpoint
$eventNotification->setIncludeDocuments('true');
# Allows you to see this in the DocuSign Admin Connect logs section
$eventNotification->setLoggingEnabled('true');
$envelopeEvents = [];
# In this case we only add a single envelope event, when the envelope is completed. You can also add events for recipients
$envelopeEvent = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeEvent();
$envelopeEvent->setEnvelopeEventStatusCode('completed'), 
$envelopeEvent->setIncludeDocuments('true');
array_push($envelopeEvents, $envelopeEvent);   
$eventNotification->setEnvelopeEvents($envelopeEvents);
$envelopeDefinition->setEventNotification($eventNotification);
```